# Find the Integral curves of: ${dx\over(-1)}= {dy\over(3y+4z)}= {dz\over(2y+5z)}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

While going through the concept of simultaneous differential equation, I came across following problem:

Find the Integral curves of:
$${dx\over(-1)}= {dy\over(3y+4z)}= {dz\over(2y+5z)}$$

The solution says: Each of these fractions of the given system of equations is equal to :

$${(dx-dy)\over(y-z)}\; \text{and}\; {(dy+2dz)\over7(y+2z)}$$

How each of these fractions can be equal to these fractions?Is there the use of componendo-dividendo concept?if yes, how we deduced that?

Comment: Are you sure its $dx-dy$ and not $dy-dz$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the nice ancient mathematics. The original equations form three proportions. Proportions fulfill this identity:

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\iff\frac{a+c}{b+d}=\frac{a}{b}$$

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\iff ad=bc\iff ab+ad=ab+bc\iff a(b+d)=b(a+c)\iff\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$$

Similarly for the difference. So, this is wrong:

$${(dx-dy)\over(y-z)}\; \text{and}\; {(dy+2dz)\over7(y+2z)}$$

Must be

$${(dy-dz)\over(y-z)}\; \text{and}\; {(dy+2dz)\over7(y+2z)}$$

and these are equal to any of the initial fractions. e.g.

$${dx\over(-1)}= {(dy-dz)\over(y-z)}$$